# Recover a deleted webpage

Tags: cache, bookmarks

Suppose, a blog or a nice article was hosted on a website and it got deleted or worse the website was brought down. How do you view that web page?

I tried searching for the cached version in Google. But, looks like the content was deleted long ago and is not listed in the search results directly. There are annotations to the link from many other sites, but still the actual content is not fully available. Now, can anybody help me see this page...

I am actually looking for http://effectize.com/become-coolest-programmer :)

And, moreover, in addition to bookmarking a favorite link, is it possible to cache the content of the link as well for later reference in case it gets deleted?

EDIT: Looks like a URL can be cached for future reference. Try: http://backupurl.com/

Comment: I suggest wikifying it to prevent from closing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Wayback machine at http://webarchive.org/? It has a partial history of a lot of websites.

As for your second question - there's nothing built into any browser (other than saving the web page on your hard disk - but I suspect that's not what you're asking for) that I know of that will do that, but I'm willing to bet there's a Firefox extension for it.

Comment: i have. :) Didn't work.

Comment: I've found it partially useful, but I wasn't after anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, that particular blog posting was largely just a summary of various related articles:
[89 Ways for You to Become the Greatest Developer in the World](http://cat-hackers.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=130&t=3331)

> And, moreover, in addition to bookmarking a favorite link, is it possible to cache 
>   the content of the link as well for later reference in case it gets deleted?

You can simply save an entire webpage for offline reading, this applies mostly to static webpages, though. Also, you can use a so called web spider to recursively download a whole website for offline use.

Comment: ScrapBook is an excellent add-in for FireFox for storing bookmarked pages offline.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked archive.org but it could find any trace of effectize.com

Might I recommend another link?

[How to be a Programmer: A Short, Comprehensive, and Personal Summary](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html)

Comment: I found 8 pages from 2008 but did not read them! Very slow recovery!!
Internet Archive   http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://effectize.com